# In a typical login situation, how many pages need to be secured with SSL?

Tags: html, security, ssl, https

For example suppose I have login.html which POSTs username and password to verify.html.  Do I need to have login.html under SSL or is just verify.html enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s a summary:

- *login.html* **must** be protected, otherwise its content could be tampered, e. g. by changing the form’s action location.
- *verify.html* **must** be protected, otherwise the credentials are not protected and could be eavesdropped.
- Everything else after a successful authentication *should* to be protected, otherwise authentication information such as a session ID could be eavesdropped.

Comment: Don't forget the landing page (e.g. index.hml). If it is not secured an attacker can simply change the login link from SSL to non-SSL.

Answer (score 1):

From a technical point of view, securing is the bare minimum. Securing login.html too will bring 3 more advantages:

1. The browser will know it is handling sensible informations, hence enforcing security policies
2. The user, what is most important, will know he is dealing with a secured application as the navigation bar will show a lock.
3. Man in middle attacks attempting to change the target of the login (to steal the credentials) will not be possible any more.

In anyway, this is a good practice to offer SSL for each part of the site handling personal data as more and more user wants their personal information to be kept confidential.